# Posso usar a mesma SSH em dois Computadores diferentes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Galera, tenho dois computadores, um desktop e um notbook, ambos com Ubuntu 18. minha duvida é: eu posso usar a mesma SSH nos dois? não quero ter que ficar adicionando as duas chaves em servidores remotos...

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim utilizar a mesma chave SSH nas duas máquinas. Entretanto é importante lembrar que, quanto mais dispositivos usarem essa chave, mais valiosa ela será, de uma perspectiva de segurança. É sempre importante levar em conta segurança vs comodidade, dependendo da criticidade que essa chave possua, pode não ser uma boa ideia tê-la em múltiplos dispositivos. Existe essa [resposta](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40061/66429), que fala, justamente, sobre a relação entre comodidade e segurança, quanto mais seguro você quiser que seja um mecanismo, menos comodidade ele terá.

Para utilizar a mesma chave, basta copiar os arquivos gerados pelo `ssh-keygen` e colocá-los disponíveis no diretório .ssh.